# event_member does not return all members

Tags: facebook, events

event_member does not return all members.

event_member seems to not have the member who is not public.

Also the sample event in the document.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event_member/

Answer (score 0):

> event_member seems to not have the member who is not public.

Well, when you think about the meaning of *„not public”*, that seems quite logical, doesn’t it …?

Is this for an event you own and access with an according access token, or for someone else’s public event?